# Multiple Aurelia Instances - Aurelia Webpack Plugin - aureliaApp option - "module not found"

Tags: aurelia

I am composing my web app as a number of Aurelia "feature" apps - although I'm not using Aurelia features as such. Consequently in my html markup I have two entry points pointing to different apps:

```
<!-- Top Navigation Bar --> 
<div aurelia-app="topnav"></div>

<!-- Main App--> 
<div aurelia-app="main"></div>
```

I am using webpack and everything works perfectly using the single "main" app. Webpack generates a JS file "main.bundle.js" which I include in the src tag.

Things are not so straightforward when I added the "topnav" app.  In webpack I tell the plugin to use a different aureliaApp name:

```
 new AureliaPlugin({ aureliaApp: "topnav"}),
```

and, as you can see my HTML entrypoint also calls "topnav".  Webpack generates a JS file "topnav.bundle.js" which I also include. I have a file called "topnav.ts" which contains the aurelia Cionfigure function which ends:

```
     aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("nav")));
```

And a pair of files "nav.ts", "nav.html" which constitute my viewmodel and view.

When I run the app aurelia loads and the "nav" module code executes. But I then get an error - see below.

[image: Error after aurelia module executes]

The module which it reports that it cannot find is the one entered into the HTML markup.

**Should this work? Have I missed something?**

I should add, everything seems to work. I can create and update properties in the viewmodel and these are bound to the view. It's just that this error is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong, just unsupported scenario. Per official doc-wiki: https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/wiki/AureliaPlugin-options#aureliaapp

You can have only 1 auto entry module with `aureliaApp` configuration. To solve this, you just need to add `PLATFORM.moduleName('topnav')` to your `main.ts` (and put it on root level)

Another way to do is to bootstrap manually:

```ts
// in your index.ts
import { bootstrap } from 'aurelia-bootstrapper';

// bootstrap top nav application, with one instance of Aurelia
bootstrap(aurelia => {
  // do your configuration
  aurelia
    .start()
    .then(() => aurelia.setRoot(
      PLATFORM.moduleName('topnav'),
      document.querySelector('#topnav')
    );
});

// bootstrap main application, with another instance of Aurelia
bootstrap(aurelia => {
  // aurelia.use.standardConfiguration();
  // ...
  aurelia
    .start()
    .then(() => aurelia.setRoot(
      PLATFORM.moduleName('app'),
      document.querySelector('app')
    )
});
```

Comment: Hi @bigopon - thanks for this. Can you explain what you mean when you say "To solve this, you just need to add PLATFORM.moduleName('topnav') to your main.ts (and put it on root level)"???  I'm clearly not getting something - my apologies. J

Comment: the error `Cannot find module with ID` happened because you didn't tell Webpack to put that module into your bundle, neither via configuration, nor via import statement in code. You can do it either way to add `topnav.ts` to your bundle, so doing `PLATFORM.moduleName` is better, because `AureliaWebpackPlugin` will also scan for matching html to put in the bundle for you

Comment: More thanks @bigopon  -  went for the manual bootstrapping and finally have this working with not an error in sight.

Comment: Hi @bigopon - Can I just check something here. In the example above where I am manually bootstrapping 2 aurelia instances, are these **completely separate**.  Each "app" references some common modules which are injected into modules in each app. Could a singleton instance in one app appear in the other?  I'm also using Aurelia-Store.  Would this save state across both "apps"?

Comment: Yes. they are completely separate. What you can do is to create a store instance in advance, before bootstrapping those apps, and register with the container in aurelia instance via: `aurelia.container.registerInstance(Store, myAlreadyCreatedStore)`