# Composing a large'ish Aurelia app - multiple apps on one page

Tags: aurelia

So I have a large application which is composed of features. Each feature is accessible via a menu which essentially loads a web page containing an aurelia app for that particular feature.  This is working fine as it allows me to complete a feature at a time and use potentially different client-side technologies as I go.

However, I now need to have more than one Aurelia app on a single page: the "feature" app described above and a "navbar" app which will always sit in the top navbar.  The arrangement is thus like below.

[image]

I am using webpack with the aurelia webpack plugin. I have tried various arrangements to get this to work, but I hit issues at every turn. My current model is to manually bootstrap the the "feature" app and the "nav" app from a single webpack config file:

```
entry: {
    packages: [
        "main","nav"
    ]
},
```

In each of these modules I manually bootstrap, for example:

```
bootstrap((aurelia: Aurelia) => {
    // init code
    aurelia.start())
    .then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app"), document.querySelector("#packages-app")));});
```

So, the "features" app is loaded into a particular DOM element, similarly for the "nav" app.

**My questions**

1. Is this a supported or even an appropriate way to split functionality?
2. I seem to get code in one module affecting the other. Is there any way an Aurelia component which is DI injected into modules in each app have shared state?

Answer (score 2):

This is a totally valid scenario, as answered in another question by you at [Aurelia Webpack Plugin - aureliaApp option - "module not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842870/aurelia-webpack-plugin-aureliaapp-option-module-not-found/54851254)

> Is this a supported or even an appropriate way to split functionality?

Yes it's a totally valid scenario and you are probably not alone doing this

> I seem to get code in one module affecting the other. Is there any way an Aurelia component which is DI injected into modules in each app have shared state?

Normally in Aurelia apps, DI is leveraged to handle this. so what you can do is to 
register your store instance in advance, for example:

```ts
// in your index.ts
import { bootstrap } from 'aurelia-bootstrapper';

// precreate store instance
const the_one_and_only_store = new Store(initState, options);

// bootstrap top nav application, with one instance of Aurelia
bootstrap(aurelia => {
  // do your configuration
  aurelia.container.registerInstance(Store, the_one_and_only_store);

  aurelia
    .start()
    .then(() => aurelia.setRoot(
      PLATFORM.moduleName('topnav'),
      document.querySelector('#topnav')
    );
});

// bootstrap main application, with another instance of Aurelia
bootstrap(aurelia => {
  // aurelia.use.standardConfiguration();
  // ...
  aurelia.container.registerInstance(Store, the_one_and_only_store);

  aurelia
    .start()
    .then(() => aurelia.setRoot(
      PLATFORM.moduleName('app'),
      document.querySelector('app')
    )
});
```

Now all `Store` injection in both apps will be pointed to your only store.

Comment: Thank you @bigopon. I felt my other question did not give the context hence me posting this. Good to get validation of the approach. So, unless I explicity register some component in each app, there is no shared state between the apps. I keep finding that one app appears to be affected by actions in the other and I am struggling to work out how.

Comment: You mean even with separation of container root/aurelia instances they are behavior weirdly? can you help give a repro based on this https://codesandbox.io/s/y41qjr36j

Comment: Thanks @bigopon - I appreciate your help. I'm convinced my issues are to do with the way I am using webpack, which I cannot reproduce in the codesandbox. I think I have made a fundamental error - perhaps you can confirm. I have been using 2 x webpack config files: one with my "main" aurelia app as the entry point which generates "main.bundle.js"; the other with the "nav" aurelia app as entry point generating "nav.bundle.js". When I include both in the webpage I get errors "Cannot redefine property: Loader". I'm thinking I can only have one. Probably doesn't even make sense ;-{

Comment: To continue - I have now refactored such the the "nav" app is an entry point in the webpack config along with "main". I generate one JS bundle file per HTML page. This bundle includes modules for both "nav" and "main" Aurelia apps. And now it all works!  My comment about interation between each aurelia app was in fact (I think) the fact that I was executing two webpack JS bundles with duplicate module definitions - and consequently, errors being displayed.  I may well post my final config for others.

Comment: That's awesome. Please aim for a discourse thread, or a blog post. Something we can shoot up for more visibility for other folks