# How to split Aurelia.js site into two parts

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack, aurelia, multiple-sites

I have an application that has two sites:

1. Landing site - with product info and e-commerce site where users can buy services
2. Administration site - where user can manage bought services, add users etc..

Each of the site has it's own css and jscript.

My idea is to have a "Login" link on the Landing site that will lead logged in users to the administration site.
If I take an usual aurelia folder setup, I will have a "src" folder.

What then?
Create subfolder per each site and then put all site assets in that subfolder?

How is best to connect two sites in aurelia application?

Do I use child router or something else?

I am using asp.net core as backend with webpack template created with dotnet new...

Please help

Thanks

Comment: I think your Q has is similar to another Q, to which I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54874085/6672580

Can you have a look at that?

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look and see if it fits.